# Understanding gcov output with fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, gcov

I am trying to understand the output of gcov on a large fortran code. I am a bit puzzled by what happens in some declaration section:

```
        1:   24:    real(kind=dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:)   :: compgo, g_rado
        1:   25:    real(kind=dp), allocatable, dimension(:,:,:) :: dd
        1:   26:    real(kind=dp), allocatable, dimension(:)     :: cpo, dcapdro &
        1:   27:        grado, gradado, &
        1:   28:        vaissalao
        1:   29:    real(kind=dp),  allocatable, dimension(:)    :: work
        3:   30:    real(kind=dp), dimension(nchim)              :: dxchimg, xchimg, z_bar
        2:   31:    real(kind=dp), dimension(nchim+1)            :: xchimgrad
        -:   32:    real(kind=dp)                                :: ad, add, beta, 
        -:   33:    real(kind=dp)                                :: mu_cz
        -:   34:    real(kind=dp)                                :: s_env
        -:   35:    integer                                      :: n_out, ll
        -:   36:    integer, save                                :: m_l
        -:   37:    logical, save                                :: init=.true.
```

Could you explain why the lines where arrays are declared are executed according to gcov while other aren't ? And why the number is not always 1 ?
On some other routines, I do not have the same behaviour:

```
       65:   89:    real (kind=dp), allocatable, dimension(:)       :: l, m, p, pt
      195:   90:    real (kind=dp),              dimension(nchim)   :: dxchim, depsx, xchim
      130:   91:    real (kind=dp),              dimension(ne)      :: f, dfdq
        -:   92:    real (kind=dp),              dimension(5)       :: epsilon
```

Thanks !

**EDIT 1:**

These codes are extracted from two subroutines, each one included in a different modules.

The first code is called once while the other is called several time (which solve the question of the large number of calls).

The code is compile using `gfortran`:

```
gfortran -Og -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage
```

Comment: Where do the lines of code come from? Where are those arrays declared? Modules? Subroutines? Functions? Internal subroutines or functiins? The code matters, show at least some salient bits.

Comment: Also, tell us how the code was compiled. Which compiler? Which compiler flags? The compiler will use some.mechanism to allocate local non-allocatable arrays, but it could be `malloc`, it coupd be on the stack (e.g. `alloca`) or it could be something else.

Comment: Was the second routine called 65-times or how many times? Really, we need the details.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited my question. gcov is really new for me so I don't really what matters and what don't.